# how to convert a struct to a map using a specific field as key?

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

I'm trying to convert this struct

```golang
type news struct {
    Id       string `json:"id"`
    Title    string `json:"title"`
    Author   string `json:"author"`
    Date     string `json:"date"`
    Escraped string `json:"escraped"`
    Page     string `json:"page"`
    Body     string `json:"body"`
    Url      string `json:"url"`
}
```

To a map where the Id is the key, today when I encode this struct I have the following json that I return in my function

```json
[
  {
    "id": "someId",
    "title": "something",
    "author": "something",
    "date": "something",
    "escraped": "something",
    "page": "https://something",
    "body": "something",
    "url": "https://something"
  }
]
```

But now I would like to change it and use the id as the key, so I would like to return

```json
[
  {
    "someId": {
      "title": "something",
      "author": "something",
      "date": "something",
      "escraped": "something",
      "page": "https://something",
      "body": "something",
      "url": "https://something"
    }
  }
]
```

I'm not very sure in how to change it to start using the ID as the key and not as a regular field anymore, I tried to create another map but I failed.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making a few assumptions here:

- You are using the `news` struct elsewhere and the fields must remain as-is
- The data you are attempting to encode is read from a slice of `[]news`

You would do this in 3 steps:

1. Make the the `Id` field optional using `omitempty`
2. Define and allocate a map of type `map[string]news` using `make()`
3. Iterate over your data to populate the `map`

### Update struct

```golang
type news struct {
    Id       string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Title    string `json:"title"`
    Author   string `json:"author"`
    Date     string `json:"date"`
    Escraped string `json:"escraped"`
    Page     string `json:"page"`
    Body     string `json:"body"`
    Url      string `json:"url"`
}
```

### Create the Map

```golang
result := make(map[string]news)
```

### Populate the Map

```golang
// Transform a slice of news (called data) to a map (called result)
for _, entry := range data {
  result[entry.Id] = news{
     Title: entry.Title,
     Author: entry.Author,
     Date: entry.Date,
     Escraped: entry.Escraped,
     Page: entry.Page,
     Body: entry.Body,
     Url: entry.Url,
  }
}
// Encode the map
encoded, _ := json.Marshal(result)
```

Output:

```json
{"someId":{"title":"something","author":"something","date":"something","escraped":"something","page":"https://something","body":"something","url":"https://something"}}
```

See example here: https://play.golang.org/p/8z6M8HqCVgv

Comment: Wonderful!  I just realized the sample entries have hard-coded values instead of the values derived from the current "entry"

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type news struct {
  Id       string `json:"id"`
  Title    string `json:"title"`
  Author   string `json:"author"`
  Date     string `json:"date"`
  Escraped string `json:"escraped"`
  Page     string `json:"page"`
  Body     string `json:"body"`
  Url      string `json:"url"`
}

func main() {
  m := &news{Id: "222"}
  result := convert(m)
  str, _ := json.Marshal(result)
  fmt.Println(string(str))
}

func convert(m *news) interface{} {
  type tmp struct {
    *news
    Id string `json:"id,omitempty"`
  }
  t := &tmp{news: m}
  return map[string]interface{}{m.Id: t}
}
```

Comment: neat. The pointer is superfluous. (https://play.golang.org/p/fLq_j_TSNDt)

Comment: I am accustomed to using pointers, and it can reduce the cost of passing values

Comment: what do you mean by "it can reduce the cost of passing values" ? Because pointers needs to copy the pointed data to the heap, that is, de facto, slow.

Comment: to be more precise, a pointer can point to the stack, only and only if, the escape analysis can prove the variable wont escape. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28485021/4466350